# Prove that when AC matrices are multiplied and equal the identity matrix the solution of Ax=b is consistent for all real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Continuing on my newbie dive into linear algebra I have this problem:

Suppose that $A = [a_{ij}]$ $m×n$ and $C = [c_{ij}]$ $n×m$ and $AC = I$ .
Prove that the system Ax = b is consistent for every $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$

Comment: $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}?$

Comment: @TheNumber23 yes, forgot to include that, i'll edit now.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I thought they may be related/asking the same question in a different way but I'm not sure of it, hence asking potentially the same question twice. If they are the same, would you please explain to me why?

Comment: They're not the same. This one's multiplied on the right

Comment: @TBrendle so the way it would be solved is Ax=b -> AxC=bC -> xI=bC -> x=bC?

Comment: @n8sty if $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ then $bC$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TheNumber23 care to explain why? Sorry this is so pedantic.

Comment: @n8sty So $b$ has $m$ rows and $1$ column. $C$ has $n$ rows and $m$ columns. Just try mulitplying in that order you won't get a vector.

Comment: @TheNumber23 I get that, thanks, silly error. So what should the solution look like?

Comment: @n8sty look at the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I misunderstood the meaning of consistent. We are just looking for at least one solution. Let $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Then $ACb=b$ which implies that $Cb$ Is a solution to eh equation $Ax=b$. This solution may not be unique. I wasn't able to come up with a quick example but it will only be guaranteed to be unique if $m=n$.